# Redirect to a page after timeout period in Django

Tags: python, django, web-applications

I am building a quiz application where the user can take up a quiz from a list of available quizzes. The quiz should be completed within a stipulated time (which is set by the author of quiz).

So once the user starts a quiz, I want a timer to start running and once the timer completes, I want the user to be redirected to his/her home page.

I can't use session timeout because that would logout the user from the application. Is there anything that Django provides out of the box for such use case? If not, is there any way to achieve this?

An enhancement to this feature (at some later point of time) would be to save the quiz without completing it, and resuming it later. So if the total duration for quiz is 5 minutes, I can take the test for 2 minutes and then resume sometime later. In which case, while resuming, the total available time should be 3 minutes for me. This means I will also have to save the state of timer.

Comment: I know its a hacky solution but you could use threads and compare current time with past time using `time.time()` and the Python threading module. Plus this way you have the ability to change the time duration at any given interval.

Comment: This is a client function and has to run on the client (in this case in the browser) as Java Script.